# Trajectory of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's public available materials, and came across this recitation question early on:

Suppose that a trajectory of $(3x^2 - y)dx + (3y^2- x)dy = 0$ contains the point $(1,1)$.  Show that it also contains the points $(1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$.

I'm embarrassed to say that I do not see why this should be so.  Certainly we can write

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{y - 3x^2}{3y^2 - x}
\end{align}

to see that at $(1,1)$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1$, at $(1,-1)$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = -2$, at $(0,1)$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3}$, and at $(1,0)$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3$, but I do not understand how we can say anything about why these points must lie on the same trajectory.  (I also note that not only does it not make sense to write $y$ as a function of $x$ on any interval $x = 1$ (since $y(x)$ would have two distinct values at $x = 1$), but that it similarly does not make sense to write $x$ as a function of $y$ on any interval containing $y = 1$, for the same reason.  I'm not sure that this is relevant, however.)

I recognize that this is an elementary exercise, but I'm stuck nevertheless, and would appreciate a gentle push in the right direction.

Comment: The form is $d(x^3+y^3-xy)$.

Comment: @Thomas, that could perhaps go as an answer, since it says all there is to say?

Comment: well, perhaps the level is not connected, you have to prove something...draw a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas points out, your differential equation can be written
$$
d\bigl(x^3+y^3-xy\bigr)=0.
$$
Thus, you are interested in the curves
$$
x^3+y^3-xy=C.
$$
Inserting the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$, we find that $C=1$. It is then easy to verify that the other points also satisfies $x^3+y^3-xy=1$. It remains to verify that the curve $x^3+y^3-xy=1$ is connected (so that we will arrive at all points). I attach a graph of the curve, together with the vector field and the interesting points marked.

[image: vector field]

Comment: You can also solve the D.E. with different initial conditions such as $y(1)=1, y(1)=-1$ and etc and check that the results are same.

Answer (score 0):

By Poincar´e operators we mean the translation operator along the trajectories of the associated differential system and the first return (or section) map defined on the cross section of the torus by means of the flow generated by the vector field. The translation operator is sometimes also called as Poincar´e–Andronov or Levinson or, simply, T-operator.